# Is it possible to make LazyRow/LazyColumn display a certain amount of items on the screen without passing in an explicit DP width

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to make a `LazyRow`/`Row` display for example 2 items on the screen simultaneously without measuring the screen width manually and passing the DP width to the children of the `LazyRow`?

Current setup example:

```
LazyRow(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(200.dp)
) {
    item {
        FirstItem(
            modifier = Modifier.width(
                ScreenUtils.getScreenWidthDP(LocalContext.current) / columnCount
            )
        )
    }
    item {
        SecondItem(
            modifier = Modifier.width(
                ScreenUtils.getScreenWidthDP(LocalContext.current) / columnCount
            )
        )
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did my answer solved your question? If so, please accept it using a checkmark under the votes counter, and upvote(if you haven't already). Otherwise let me know if you have any problems with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyItemScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).fillParentMaxWidth(kotlin.Float)) - it's available on `LazyItemScope`. For example, to display 2 items use `fraction = 0.5f`:

```
LazyRow(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(200.dp)
) {
    item {
        FirstItem(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillParentMaxWidth(0.5f)
        )
    }
    item {
        SecondItem(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillParentMaxWidth(0.5f)
        )
    }
}
```